# yii2 get activerecords by relation column

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I need to **select ActiveRecord's that have related AR's with specific column value**.

Situation: 'User' may have many 'Branches' - via junction table, and Branch is related to Department. I have `department_id`, and I want to select Users, that have branches from this single Department.

Department:

```
... $this->hasMany(Branch::className(), ['department_id' => 'id']);
```

Branch:

```
... $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
                ->viaTable('{{%user_to_branch}}',['branch_id' => 'id']);
```

The thing is, that I do not want to access this from Department in any way (e.g.  `$department->getUsers()`....), but i want to define this in `ActiveQuery`.

So i could select Users like:

```
User::find()->fromDepartment(5)->all();
```

THANK YOU in advance !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**User model method**

```
public function getBranch()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::className(), ['id' => 'branch_id'])
                ->viaTable('{{%user_to_branch}}', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public static function fromDepartment($id)
{
    $query = self::find();
    $query->joinWith(['branch'])
          ->andWhere(['department_id'=>$id]);
    return $query->all();
}
```

Usage:

```
User::fromDepartment(5);
```

Comment: Of course ! this is brilliant for me. THANKS !
I used it in ActiveQuery like:

User model:

`public static function find()
    {
       
  $q = new UserQuery(get_called_class());
  return $q->userDepartment(\Yii::$app->user->identity->department_id)->orderBy('surname ASC');
    }`

and ActiveQuery:
`class UserQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{

public function userDepartment($departmentId)
{ 
  return $this
   ->joinWith(['branches'])
   ->andWhere(['department_id'=>$departmentId]);

}
}`

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return MyActiveRecordModelQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    return new MyActiveRecordModelQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

MyActiveRecordModelQuery:

```
/**
 * @method MyActiveRecordModelQuery one($db = null)
 * @method MyActiveRecordModelQuery[] all($db = null)
 */
class MyActiveRecordModelQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fromDepartment($id)
    {
        $this->andWhere(['departament_id' => $id]); //or use relation

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyActiveRecordModelQuery::find()->fromDepartment(5)->all();
```

Comment: Thanks BUT,
I assume that `MyActiveRecordModelQuery` is for my `Department` model, but this way we select Departments, not Users :|